# Calabash-Android elements contain same text, how to select last instance index?

Tags: android, calabash

I have multiple fields with Arg1 value.  How do I select the element that's the last index?  This selects the first index with the arg1 value.

```
tap_when_element_exists("* text:'#{arg1}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a query to get all and then select the last one.
First query to get all

```
res = query "* text:'#{argh1}'"
```

Then to touch the last you can do

```
touch res[-1]
```